# Need Explanation To Understand why this CASE Expression Work In The Where Clause

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, case, where-clause

I recently ran into an issue with CASE expression in BQ, and I found a solution online in a MySQL forum, and it worked! However, I'm not quite satisfied because I can't seem to understand how the expression works, and no one in that forum explained either.

Summary BQ queries:

```
Select *
From Data_Table
Where Fiscal_Year in ('2021', '2022')
And Case  
    WHEN FYW = '202251' AND date_diff(Return_Date, Delivery_Date, day) >= 150 
    THEN 0 
    ELSE 1 
    End = 1
```

I'm used to using CASE with, for example:

```
When Age < 18  Then 'Not old enough to drive'
When Age <= 70 Then 'Old to drive'
Else 'Should drive less'
End As 'Status of Driving Age'
```

What do 0 and 1 mean in the solution of the CASE expression above, and how does 'End = 1' work?

If the date_diff is 138 days, does it become 1 or stay the at 137 days?

If the date_diff is 160 days, does it become 0 or get ignored?

Thank you everyone for the help and sharing the knowledge.

Comment: That where+case simplifies to `where Fiscal_Year in ('2021', '2022') and not (FYW = '202251' and date_diff(Return_Date, Delivery_Date, day) >= 150)`

Comment: ...and to amplify on @Rajat, applying DeMorgan's rule to that further simplifies it to `where Fiscal_Year in ('2021', '2022') and (FYW<>'202251' OR date_diff(Return_Date, Delivery_Date, day)<150)`.

Comment: The original is just a clumsy way of someone saying, 'Let me tell you what I don't want'.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers.

Comment: Think of the WHERE clause as being " ... WHERE ... AND x = y".  In your particular example, then, the "x" is represented by everything from the word CASE to the word END, and then "y" is represented by the final 1

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE` expression above is a **simple CASE expression format** and it was used in a `WHERE` clause. The `WHEN` expression returns a result if the condition is met, if not, the `ELSE` expression will be the result. `WHERE` clause also filter the criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what does 0 and 1 mean there?

If the date_diff is 138 days, does it become 1 or stay the at 137 days?

If the date_diff is 160 days, does it become 0 or get ignored?